# Why does my UIAlertController not appear until the second time I press it's tab?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am using the following class to try and make an alert popup when I click on a specific tab (rather than switching to that tab). The first time I click the tab it goes to an empty view and does not show the alert.

The second time I click it (and beyond) it works as intended.

Is there a way to make the alert fire the first time I click the tab?

Code for the class is below:

```
class TabOverlayViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.tabBarController?.delegate = self

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

        if viewController == tabBarController.viewControllers?[1] {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Album", style: .default) { action in

            })
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {

            })

            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: print something inside `self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {` and see if it gets printed in the console when clicking the first time.

Comment: I'd set your tabBarControllerDelegate in viewDidLoad, not viewWillappear. viewDidLoad executes when the view loads the first time. viewWillAppear executes when the view will appear, so it can execute multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you set `UITabBarViewControllerDelegate` only in `viewWillAppear` method. So first time there is no delegate's call, view appears, sets delegate and involves `func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool` method only on following taps.

**UPD:**

By the way, are you sure that this particular controller should be a delegate for `UITabBarController`? Is it correct that concrete controller decides which tab could be opened and which not? In a simple app I would assign to delegate tab bar controller itself:

```
final class TabBarVC: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = self
    }
}

extension TabBarVC: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
       // do your logic here
    }
}
```

Of course, you should specify, that your current tab bar controller is type of `TabBarVC`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Do you know how I can set it early enough that the alert appears the first time?

Comment: Try in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Yikes good catch. Moved it to the main UITabBarController and viewDidLoad() function and it works. Thank you!